# Yii 1.1.16 - renderPartial() adds a space at begining of output

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

Is it just me, or does `renderPartial()` add an extra space in front of its output? It seems to do so with all my `renderPartial()`'s. `render()`works fine for me and doesn't add an extra space.

here is a sample code of mine. Trying to generate an RSS, and getting error's because of the extra space

```
public function actionFeed()
    {
        Yii::import('site.common.extensions.feed.*');

        $model = new ABC();

        $this->renderPartial('feed', array('model' => $model->findAll()));
    }
```

here is the generated html

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"><channel>
```

there is a space in front of `<?xml>`

if i empty my `feed.php` and just put

```
<span>asadadasfaf</span>
```

there would still be a space in front of `<span>`

I'm using this extension to generate the RSS https://github.com/2amigos/efeed

Because of the space, Firefox is giving me this error

```
XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
Location: http://localhost/dev/frontend/www/abc/feed/
Line Number 1, Column 2: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
-^
```

FYI, I'm using:

```
Yii 1.1.16
OSX 10.10.2
XAMPP 1.8.3-5
CHROME 40.0.2214.94 (64-bit) 
FIREFOX 35.0.1
```

Anyone know of a work around? or having the same issues?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, had a space in front of my `<?php` tag in the controller calling the action. :\

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why `renderPartial()` is adding extra space there but you can do something like this.

```
public function actionFeed()
    {
        $this->layout = '';
        $this->render('feed', array('model' => $model->findAll()));
    }
```

Because `render()` is working for you and using using `$this->layout=''` you can disable rendering layout for view.

Hope it'll work for you.

Comment: strange, getting the same results. and when i change `feed.php` to just `<h1>hello</h1>` it shows in the layout